# Applying CSS transform rotation to an element using @font-face

Tags: html, css, transform, rotation, font-face

I've been trying to apply a transform rule to some elements which also have a `@font-face` font applied to them.

```
h1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-1deg);
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
}
```

When this transform rule is applied, I get the rotation I'm after, but the text does not appear correctly — although it's rotated, it's as though each character is bound to an origin which sits on a pixel, and so the line of text looks jagged.

If I simply replace the font with a system font, the problem goes away, so would appear to be related to the use of `@font-face`. I've tested it in a variety of browsers on OS X and Windows, and they all show similar results.

Has anybody come across this problem before, or can anybody give any advice on why this might be occurring?

Comment: When you say jagged, do you mean it isn't anti-aliased?

Comment: It's antialised, and the text is being rotated, but it seems as though each character is anchored to an origin which is located on a pixel grid.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source for this [experiment](http://simurai.com/post/861975259/css3-tilt-shift-text).

It uses @font-face with rotate as well as some other nifty CSS3 effects.

Comment: Nice demo Josiah. Unfortunately, doesn't help me get to the bottom of this issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles to `<h1>` element:

```
-webkit-backface-vivbility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Comment: 1) typo: webkit-backface-visibility  2) -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); after -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg); will overwrite the original...  Just adding -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d to the original did the trick for me.